# Как в Си привести массив символов к числу?

Tags: массивы, c, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Си привести массив символов к числу? Как только не пытался, ничего не получается :(

Comment: И как именно Вы только не пытались?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: приведите пример

Comment: видимо так:)

    char * a = "1234";
    int b = (int)a;
    int c = <reinterpret_cast>(int)(a);

могу ещё десяток вариантов придумать.

p.s. для ЧБЮ - это моя попытка угадать, что там ТС пытался написать, но я знаю, что этот код не будет работать как нужно.

Comment: Вы правы:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@Jeremen1](/users/8698/jeremen1)](/users/8698/jeremen1), если "по простому", то есть 3 вида приведения типа.

1) Преобразование плавающего из одной длины в другую. Реально меняются длины мантиссы и порядка.

2) Перевод целого в плавающее (и наоборот, всегда с отбрасыванием дробной части). При этом **на самом деле** меняется тип значения, т.е. его машинный формат, именно формат, а не только длина цепочки бит.

3) "Преобразование" одного целого в другое (если у них разный размер, то мененяется длина цепочки бит, представляющей число в машшином виде). Преобразования знаковых в беззнаковые одинакового размера **"на самом деле"** не происходит. Ничего не меняется, только интерпретация результатов работы **тех же самых** электронных схем.

Все указатели являются целыми (того же размера, что и long).

Вот и все "секреты".

Answer (score 1):

если вы хотите привести массив цифровых символов в целое число то видимо надо так

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  char * s = "12345";

    cout << atoi(s) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: > - [\**[Отсюда\]**](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/stdlib.h/atoi.php) The atoi function has been deprecated by strtol and should not be used in new code.

- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792663/atol-v-s-strtol

Comment: спасибо. получилось. а есть что-то подобное только чтобы не в int, а в float?

Comment: посмотрели бы рядом - [strtof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/) и [strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/).

Comment: @Jeremen1, по аналогии с strtol() (string to long) есть strtod() (string to double).

Открою "страшную тайну". В конце `man strtol` есть раздел `SEE ALSO` (в других man-ах он тоже  есть). Рекомендую читать.

Comment: если в плавающее то вместо atoi надо использовать atof аналогично первой.

котик я с тобой согласен но парень спрашивает как делать в Cи, а метки стоят C, C++ этот способ работает и там и там

Comment: Ну, `strto*` есть и в C, [пруф](http://ideone.com/iLrzqO).