# Как преобразовать массив символов char[] в int?

Tags: c++, типы-данных, преобразование, преобразование-типов

Есть массив символов, как преобразовать его в int?

```
char buffer[255] = "154306";
int a = buffer; //хочется чтобы переменная a была равна 154306
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в Си привести массив символов к числу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/194230/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a1%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для преобразования C-строки в значение типа `int` есть по крайней мере следующие способы:

- Функция [`std::atoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)

```
#include <cstdlib>
...
char buffer[256] = "12345";
int val = std::atoi(buffer);

cout << val;
```

Если не удалось преобразовать строку в число (пустая строка, или последовательность символов в строке не представляет число), то функция возвращает ноль.
Если строка содержит число, но оно не представимо типом `int`, то поведение функции не определено.

- Функция [`std::sscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

```
#include <cstdio>
...
char buffer[256] = "12345";
int val = 0;

int result = std::sscanf(buffer, "%d", &val);
if (result == EOF) {
    //Входная строка пустая
} else if (result == 0) {
    //Не удалось преобразовать строку в число
} else {
    cout << val;
}
```

Если строка содержит число, но оно не представимо типом `int`, то поведение функции не определено.

- Функция [`std::strtol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cerrno>
#include <limits>
...
char buffer[256] = "12345";

char* buffer_end = nullptr;
int saved_errno = errno;
errno = 0;
long lval = strtol(buffer, &buffer_end, 10);
int cur_errno = errno;
errno = saved_errno;
if (buffer == buffer_end) {
    //Не удалось преобразовать строку в число
} else if (cur_errno != 0) {
    //Переполнение при преобразовании в число
} else if (lval < std::numeric_limits<int>::min() || lval > std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) {
    //Переполнение при преобразовании в число
} else {
    int val = static_cast<int>(lval);
    cout << val;
}
```

- `std::string` + функция [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
...
char buffer[256] = "12345";

try {
    int val = std::stoi(std::string(buffer));
    cout << val;
} catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
    //Не удалось преобразовать строку в число
} catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
    //Переполнение при преобразовании в число
}
```

- [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
#include <sstream>
...
char buffer[256] = "12345";
int val = 0;

std::stringstream stream;
stream << buffer;
stream >> val;

if (stream.fail()) {
    //Либо не удалось преобразовать строку в число
    //Либо переполнение при преобразовании в число
} else {
    cout << val;
}
```

- Функция [`std::from_chars()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars)

```
#include <charconv>
#include <system_error>
#include <cstring>
...
char buffer[256] = "12345";
int val = 0;

auto res = std::from_chars(buffer, buffer + std::strlen(buffer), val);
if (res.ec == static_cast<std::errc>(0)) {
    cout << val;
} else if (res.ec == std::errc::invalid_argument) {
    //Не удалось преобразовать строку в число
} else if (res.ec == std::errc::result_out_of_range) {
    //Переполнение при преобразовании в число
}
```

`std::from_chars()` — единственная из представленных функций, на которую не влияют текущие глобальные локали. Но в отличие от других способов, данная функция не игнорирует ведущие пробельные символы в строке. Также неотрицательные числа не могут начинаться с символа `+`.

Answer (score 5):

Посмотрите на функции [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) или более мощную [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: Так вроде же [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BChttps://yandex.ru)?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Давайте уберем ссылки вообще - ответ останется полным и самодостаточным: *Посмотрите на функции `atoi` или более мощную `strtol`.* В данном случае ссылка - *дополнение* к ответу, чтобы вопросителю :) было легче найти нужную информацию, а не собственно ответ.