# Проверка на выход за пределы int

Tags: c++, int, overflow

[Настасья](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/347091/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8F) хотела спросить : [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280905/Проверка-на-выход-за-пределы-int/1280957#1280957](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280905/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-int/1280957#1280957)

> Я перевожу string в int через std::atoi(), однако строка может
> превышать диапазон значений int (внутри string может быть больше 2 147
> 483 647)
>
> Думала проверять по количеству символов, если больше 7, чтобы выдавать
> ошибку и далее проверять посимвольно строку на максимальное число.
> Проблема возникает, если я выполняю арифметические операции,
> происходит выход за пределы. Как правильно проверить выходит ли число
> за пределы своего значения?

Я пытался ответить так :

> Есть такое понятие как двухфакторная аутентификация. В нашем случае
> прочитайте число из строки, переведите в новую строку и сравните.
>
> ```
> # include <string>
> # include <sstream>
> # include <iostream>
> bool isBADstrtoint(std::string const & st,int & in) {
>     int i = std::atoi(st.c_str());
>     std::stringstream ss;
>     ss << i;
> std:: cout<<"ss.str = '"<<ss.str()<<"'"<<std::endl;
>     if (st == ss.str()) {
>         in = i ;
>         return false ; }
>     return true ; }
>
> int main(){
>     int i;
>     std::string st = "12345678901";
>     if( isBADstrtoint(st,i))
>       std::cout<<"st = '"<<st <<"' is bad"<<std::endl;  
>     else
>       std::cout<<"i = "<<i <<std::endl;
> }
> ```
>
> Работает только с целыми числами, экспонету не принимает.
>
> ```
> ss.str = '-539222987'
> st = '12345678901' is bad
> ```
>
> При работе с арифметическими операциями вы должны уже сразу сами
> проверять переполнение.
>
> ```
> int x, y , s ;
> s = x + y ;
> if ( y > 0 )
>   if ( s > x )
>     Ok
>   else 
>     Bad
> else
>   if ( y < 0 )
>     if ( s < x )
>       Ok
>     else
>       Bad
> ```

Но мой ответ был негативно оценён. Сказали что при строках, которые не могут представлять числа этого типа, компилятор может возвращать любое число и дальнейшее выполнение никак не гарантирует ход выполнения кода программы, которое использует это возвращаемое значение.

То-же самое со сложением чисел. Если происходит переполнение, то компилятор не гарантирует адекватный ответ при сравнении равенства `==` или `<`.

> Вот вам реальный пример, когда при наступлении UB тип int ведёт себя
> так, словно диапазон представимых им значений больше, чем есть на
> самом деле. – [wololo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/262953/wololo)
>
> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <limits>
> #include <type_traits>
> using std::cout;
> using std::endl;
>
> int main()
> {
>   volatile int tmp = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
>   
>   int a = tmp;
>   
>   cout << "a+1 > a: " << ( int(a+1) > a ) << endl;
>   
>   cout << "a+1:     " << int(a+1)      << endl;
>   cout << "a:       " << a             << endl;
> }
>
> g++ -std=c++2a -O3 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
> a+1 > a: 1
> a+1:     -2147483648
> a:       2147483647
> ```

Как проверять, что число в строке может быть предоставлено типом **int** правильно?

Comment: Проверить саму строку, если известно, что она состоит только из цифр, можно сравнением со строкой, представляющей MAX_INT. Сложнее выполнить проверки арифметических действий.

Comment: С одной стороны, можно пройтись по строке посимвольно, и проанализировать, представимо хранимое в ней число типом `int` или нет. Но с другой стороны, на функции `atoi` свет клином не сошёлся. Стандартная библиотека предоставляет и другие способы преобразования строки в число, и многие из них не боятся переполнения. В ответе к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1258623) я приводил несколько вариантов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример использования проверенных библиотечных реализаций:

1. Использование boost.lexical cast для преобразования строки:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        auto const value{::boost::lexical_cast<int>("33423049234")};
        ::std::cout << "good " << value;
    }
    catch (::boost::bad_lexical_cast const & exception)
    {
        ::std::cout << "bad";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jqP7szqYf

2. Использование boost.safe numerics для контроля арифметических операций:

```
#include <boost/safe_numerics/safe_integer.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <system_error>

int main()
{
    ::boost::safe_numerics::safe<int> const x{::std::numeric_limits<int>::max()};
    ::boost::safe_numerics::safe<int> const y{1};
    try
    {
        auto const result{x + y};
        ::std::cout << "good " << static_cast<int>(result);
    }
    catch (::std::system_error const & exception)
    {
        ::std::cout << "bad " << exception.code();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Wsb5Gsjvz

Comment: Бусты не знаю, никогда не юзал. Надо попробовать. Мне wololo вешает на уши, что компилятор может любую переменную сделать другим типом. Что ответить?

Comment: @AlexGlebe Правильно вешает. Если имеется неопределенное поведение, компилятор может еще и не такое учинить. Например он может заказать пиццу или [вызвать перемещение во времени](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: Использовать `safe_numerics` нет желания. Я не люблю скрытность реализации классов. Проще просто сначала самому предохраняться, проверяя аргументы: близки ли они к `int::max`. А с `lexical_cast<int>` - это очень хорошее предложение.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ очень сильно зависит от того, что "Настасья" понимает под "правильно проверить выходит ли число за пределы своего значения".

Например, использование **расширения компилятора** - это "правильно"? Если да, то в [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html) и [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checked-arithmetic-builtins) есть примитивы для целочисленной арифметики с переполнением.

"Правильно" ли использовать **специальный API платформы**? Например, Windows [intsafe.h](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/intsafe/)?

Входит ли в понятие "правильно" **использование сторонних библиотек**? Например, [safe-math.h](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/tree/master/safe-math)

Можно ли "правильно" писать на **ассемблере**? Сделать свою реализацию функций сложения/вычитания/умножения для целевой платформы, которая проверяет Overflow флаг.

Если же под "правильно" понимается **строгое следование стандарту**, то в стандарте переполнение есть **undefined behavior**. Другими словами, нужны дополнительные проверки для результата и операндов:

1. результат сложения положительных чисел больше любого слагаемого
2. результат сложения отрицательных чисел меньше любого слагаемого
3. при произведении положительных целых чисел определить позицию старшего бита в каждом из множителей и убедиться, что сумма этих позиций строго меньше размера типа в битах.

Как-то так.

**UPDATE**

Как справедливо заметил @gbg, после того, как переполнение случилось, проверять уже поздно, ибо варианты неопределённого поведения могут быть разные. Например, включение системы самоуничтожения, как [на ракете Ariane 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_Flight_501)

Поэтому проверять надо заранее. Например, при сложении, `если a > 0 то b <= (MAX_INT - a)`

Comment: Тут есть нюанс - переполнение при операции со знаковыми числами - UB, следовательно, все последующие за ним проверки теряют смысл - они будут выполняться над бессмысленными данными.

Comment: @gbg согласен, добавил UPDATE

Comment: Есть целая глава на эту тему: https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0321335724/samplechapter/seacord_ch05.pdf

Comment: Самое правильное, это сначала проверять аргументы, а потом делать сложение. Согласен. Но писать по новой `atoi` с защитой ой как не хочется.