# Может ли быть переполнение в анонимном объекте (выражении)? С++

Tags: c++

Вопрос: как выделяется память под анонимные объекты и выражения?

Подробнее:
Сделал алгоритм Эль-Гамаля в режиме цифровой подписи. Все работает шикарно, но если числа больше ~3000, то начинается непредсказуемое поведение. Поскольку алгоритм верный, то грешу на данный участок кода:

```
unsigned mymath::powmod(unsigned base, unsigned exp, unsigned modulo)
{
    unsigned res = 1;

    while (exp != 0)
    {
        if ((exp & 1) != 0)
        {
            res = (1ll * res * base) % modulo; // 9 строка
        }   

        base = (1ll * base * base) % modulo; // 12 строка
        exp >>= 1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Скорее всего в этом коде при использовании больших чисел возникает переполнение. Вопрос: где и почему? Сами аргументы изначально имеют значение около 3000, что в пределах unsigned int, значит переполнение внутри кода. Однако внутри кода я после всех действий вычисляю остаток по модулю, что дает нам довольно скромные числа в районе тех же 3000.

Соответственно: Как выделяется память под анонимные объекты и выражения? Может ли быть внутри них переполнение?

Comment: покажите аргументы, при передаче которых начинаются проблемы

Comment: 3100, 6484, 7027 - по порядку

Comment: Сейчас провел тесты. Результат расходится именно при большой степени (exp > 1000).

Comment: [Проверка на выход за пределы int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280966/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-int/1280984#1280984) *"начинается непредсказуемое поведение"* - приведенный код ничего такого не демонстрирует, функция в нем даже не вызывается.

Comment: Какой результат должна вернуть функция при данных аргументах: `3100, 6484, 7027`?

Comment: @wololo 1286. Возможную ошибку нашел - в функцию передавал числа типа int, а нужно передавать unsigned. Скорее всего большие числа обрезались, что приводило к ошибке. Однако проблема не решена, хотя теперь ошибка появляется куда реже и уже с числами > 9000. Скорее всего переполнение где-то в другом месте. Сейчас ищу в каком.

Comment: Так она и [возвращает](https://ideone.com/eYrIqF) `1286`. Или у вас возвращает что-то другое?

Comment: После исправления возвращает все верно. Поэтому сижу и ищу ошибку в другой части кода, как и написал выше.

Comment: Какого исправления? Если вызвать приведённую в вопросе функцию с аргументами типа `int` вот так: `powmod(3100, 6484, 7027)`, то она вернёт `1286`. `сижу и ищу ошибку в другой части кода` Т.е. в вопросе вы предлагаете найти ошибку в участке кода без ошибок?

Comment: Возникает переполнение. Если `a` "хорошее" число, `b` "хорошее" число, то еще не значит, что `a * b` тоже будет "хорошим". Просто потому что, на самом деле, для БЕЗЗНАКОВЫХ k битных чисел происходит следующее: `(a * b) % c` на самом деле равно `((a * b) % (2^k)) % c`.

Comment: Я буквально недавно писал [некоторый текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1284788/327947) по поводу переполнения. Возможно, будет полезно.