# Как избежать переполнения в выражении? С++

Tags: c++, переполнение, выражение

Довольно долго искал ошибку в коде. Спасибо отладчику VS. Ошибка в этой строке:

```
this->b = ((hh * mul) % (this->p - 1));
```

this->b - переменная типа int, 4 байта. hh, mul, this->p - аналогично.
Проблема возникает, например, при числах:

```
hh = -2156842;
mul = 3059;
this->p = 3061;
```

Ошибка выходит в самом первом выражении. При перемножении отрицательного числа hh и положительным mul возникает большущее ПОЛОЖИТЕЛЬНОЕ число. Это переполнение? Как его избежать? Как выделяется память в выражениях?

Comment: `this->b = (hh % (this->p - 1)) * mul)  % (this->p - 1);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, это является переполнением.

Чтобы избежать переполнения стоит воспользоваться одним замечательным свойством сравнений по модулю: числа `a * b` и `(a % m) * (b % m)` сравнимы по модулю `m`.
Однако, нам не достаточно того, что они будут сравнимы и необходимо еще сохранить знак (я подразумеваю не выбор между `-x` или `+x`, а выбор между `x` и `x - m`, где `0 < x < m`). Но оператор `%` его сохраняет.

Стало быть, можно написать следующее:

```
auto mod = this->p - 1;
auto mul1 = hh % mod;
auto mul2 = mul % mod;
this->b = (mul1 * mul2) % mod;
```

Однако, стоит помнить, что даже такой трюк не спасет, если модуль `this->p - 1` будет слишком большим и числа `hh`, `mul` окажутся "плохими".

Память перед переменную выделяется ровно `k` бит. Если же при выполнении получается некоторое число, не влезающее в эти `k` бит, то "лишние" биты будут обрезаны. Для беззнаковых чисел это означает, что с точки зрения математики результат *a * b*, на самом деле, будет равен `(a * b) % (2^k)`. Для беззнаковых же там всё чуточку сложнее. Всё связано с представлением отрицательных чисел. Подробнее про такое представление можно почитать, например, на [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). Как знаковые, так и беззнаковые числа, зациклены. Это значит, что, если числа покрывают диапазом `[L; R]`, то `R + 1 = L`, `L - 1 = R`. Для беззнаковых `L = 0`, `R = 2^k - 1`, для беззнаковых `L = - 2^{k - 1}`, `R = 2^{k - 1} - 1`. То есть, результат `a * b`, на самом деле, равен `(a * b - L) % (R - L) + L`.

Comment: Для знаковых целых переполнение вызывает неопределённое поведение, а не зацикливание. [Пример](https://ideone.com/VLE8kj) с неработающим зацикливанием для знакового целого.

Comment: Забавно, ведь [число `val + 1` получилось таким, как я писал выше](https://ideone.com/JBpjmS). Я попробовал сперва их к инту привести и т.д., но все равно получал `false`.

Comment: Понял. Тогда как выделяется память для выражения hh * mul? Данное выражение всегда будет signed int с размером 4 байта ВО ВРЕМЯ вычисления, а потом уже после вычислений (в т.ч. с переполнением) конвертируется в тип переменной, которой присваивается значение? Или это зависит от того, какой переменной мы присваиваем выражение? Например, если присваиваем переменной uint64_t, то и вычисления в выражении будут как для uint64_t?

Comment: И насколько эффективно в код добавлять перед вычислениями 1ll * (выражение), чтобы вычисления были в формате long long? Или лучше использовать свойства модульной арифметики?

Comment: @CSharpLooser, в арифметических выражениях перед вычислением операнды приводятся к общему типу. И от типа переменной, которой происходит присвоение, тип результата арифметического выражения не зависит. Этот механизм называется _usual arithmetic conversions_. См.: [Arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic), а также [Неявное приведение типов данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/627522). Здесь `1ll * (выражение)` общим типом будет как минимум `long long` (либо как минимум `unsigned long long` если результат беззнаковый, например, `1ll * 1ull` ).

Comment: @CSharpLooser, и ещё не забывайте про ассоциативность операторов и вообще порядок вычисления выражений. Для платформ с 32-битным `int`'ом это `1ll * 2'000'000'000 * 2'000'000'000` корректный код не содержащий переполнения, т.к. он интерпретируется так: `(1ll * 2'000'000'000) * 2'000'000'000`. Но если вы сами расставите скобки вот так: `1ll * (2'000'000'000 * 2'000'000'000)`, то тут уже есть переполнение в скобках, т.к. общий тип подвыражения в скобках есть `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Ну, конечно, переполнение, что же ещё)

Сделай все типы [int64_t](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-160), его диапазон от `-9 223 372 036 854 775 808` до `9 223 372 036 854 775 807`.
`hh * mul = -6 597 779 678`, это спокойно влезет в него, но не влезет в `int`, у которого диапазон от `-2 147 483 648` до `2 147 483 647`.

**P.S.**
Правила приведения выражения к общему типу следующие:

1. Если два типа меньше `int` (`int32_t` - 4 байта), то они оба приводятся к нему

   Например, `int8_t * uint16_t = int32_t`
2. Если типы больше или равны `int`:

   1. Если типы одинаковой байтности, выбирается беззнаковый

      Например, `int32_t * uint32_t = uint32_t`
   2. Если типы разной байтности, выбирается наибольший из них

      Например, `uint32_t - int64_t = int64_t`