# реализация выброса исключений при инициализации объекта

Tags: c++, ооп, исключения

есть вот такая програма на  С++ . Она выводит суму чисел которые складывались в виде строки определенное количество раз
Например :
число : 5
сколько раз его сложить : 4
сума чисел : 6170
сами числа :
5
55
555
5555

код :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>
#include<exception>

class EqualDigitsProgression {
public:
   EqualDigitsProgression()
   {
       this->set_num(1);
       this->set_times(1);
       this->nums.reserve(this->times);
       this->insert_nums();
   }
   EqualDigitsProgression(long long int num, long long int times){
       this->set_num(num);
       this->set_times(times);
       this->nums.reserve(this->times);
       this->insert_nums();
   };
   EqualDigitsProgression(const EqualDigitsProgression& other) {
       this->set_num(other.num);
       this->set_times(other.times);
       this->nums.reserve(other.times);
       this->insert_nums();
   }

   void set_num(long long int num) {
       if (num <= 0) {
           this->num = 1;
       }
       this->num = num;
   }
   void set_times(long long int times) {
       if (times <= 0) {
           this->times = 1;
       }
       this->times = times;
   }
   long long int get_num() {
       return this->num;
   }
   long long int get_times() {
       return this->times;
   }
   std::vector<long long int> get_nums() {
       return this->nums.empty() ? std::vector<long long int>() : this->nums;

   }

   long long int calculate() {
       return std::accumulate(this->nums.begin(), this->nums.end(), 0);
   }
   long long int operator() () {
       return this->calculate();
   }
   
private:
   long long int num;
   long long int times;
   std::vector<long long int> nums;

   std::string multiplication(std::string str, int times) {
       std::string multiplicaded_str;

       for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
           multiplicaded_str += str;
       }

       return multiplicaded_str;
   }

   void insert_nums() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= this->times; i++) {
            this->nums.emplace_back(std::atoi(this->multiplication(std::to_string(this->num), i).c_str()));
        } 
       
   }

};

int main()
{
   EqualDigitsProgression edp(5,20);
   std::cout << edp.calculate() << std::endl;
   
   for (auto i : edp.get_nums()) {
       std::cout << i <<std::endl;
   }

   std::cout << "result with functor : " << edp();


}
```

переменная `times`  типа  `long long int` и тип `long long int`  вмещает только 19 цифр , а в данном примере переменная `times` имеет значение `20` что естественно же приведёт к ошибке и неправильной работе программы . Также приведет к ошибке переменная `num` ведь она тоже выйдет за пределы `long long int`
вот результат етого примера

[image: wrong result]

Вопрос : Как правильно написать исключения для переменных `times`  и `num` и главное где , в сеттерах или в конструкторе , не сломается ли програма если исключения выбросит в конструкторе ведь объект  должен инициализироваться .

еще один вопрос с теории : Как  вообще правильно работать с исключениями внутри класса .Где можно почитать или посмотреть примеры

Comment: Непонятно. Может, вам нужно использовать длинную арифметику, а не исключения выбрасывать?...

Comment: нет нужно исключение

Comment: то есть нужно сообщить пользователь что числа не подходят

Comment: Ну так смотрите, как только достигните при каком-то числе `INT_MAX/10` - бросайте ваши игры :) - например: `throw runtime_error("too large value")`

Comment: да но где ето лучше реализовать в сеттерах или в конструкторе или ето правильно по другому делается

Comment: В вашем варианте - раз вы вынесли отдельно два сеттера (я бы ограничился только конструктором) - то в обоих, потому что гарантировать, какой будет первым, какой вторым - нельзя. И именно это может помешать, кстати - скажем, были одни значения, ну, там, 1 и 10 - т.е. в пределе 1111111111, а тут вы хотите сделать 9 и 2. Меняете на 9 - и все, надо генерировать исключение, не доходя до установки 2... Так что я бы сеттеры не делал, а устанавливал значения только в конструкторе.

Comment: [Проверка на выход за пределы int](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280966/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-int/1280984#1280984)